# Where does tensorflow ops run? cpu or gpu?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        x = tf.constant(0,name='x')
        x = x * 2
    y = x + 2
    config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True) 
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(y)
```

When you run it, you will get the result.

```
mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
2017-08-11 21:38:23.953846: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows
-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:847] mul: (Mul)/job:l
ocalhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
add: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
2017-08-11 21:38:23.954846: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows
-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:847] add: (Add)/job:l
ocalhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
add/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
2017-08-11 21:38:23.954846: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows
-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:847] add/y: (Const)/j
ob:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
mul/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
2017-08-11 21:38:23.954846: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows
-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:847] mul/y: (Const)/j
ob:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
2017-08-11 21:38:23.954846: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows
-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\simple_placer.cc:847] x: (Const)/job:l
ocalhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

It means the `mul` runs on `cpu` and `add` runs on `gpu`. So I draw a conclusion that `where does ops or tensors define where does ops or tensors run`.

And when I view the [Inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L236), I confused.

```
with slim.arg_scope([slim.variables.variable], device='/cpu:0'):
    # Calculate the loss for one tower of the ImageNet model. This
    # function constructs the entire ImageNet model but shares the
    # variables across all towers.
    loss = _tower_loss(images_splits[i], labels_splits[i], num_classes,
                        scope, reuse_variables)
```

The tower_loss define on cpu, which means every gpu will run loss on cpu according to my conclusion. But I think every gpu should run a replica
on gpu. So does I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

> parent device assignment are overwritten by child device assignment.

In the following code the function `_tower_loss` has another device assignment inside `/gpu:i` (if you look at the implementation). Loss are computed using the gpus, but loss are gathered and averaged in `cpu.`

```
  loss = _tower_loss(images_splits[i], labels_splits[i], num_classes,
                    scope, reuse_variables)
```

Comment: `/gpu:i` is parent of `/cpu:0`, view [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L233), so `/cpu:0` overwrite `/gpu:i`.

Comment: here i meant parent and child using the `tree` concept. ..inner assigment are child; not parent. `gpu:i` are inner assignment

Comment: `/gpu:i` is outer of `/cpu:0`

Comment: i would suggest to look again https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py